# Before Insert and Before Update Trigger returning null for Lead Address field

Tags: apex, leads

Im trying to do some code that checks whether a user has entered a City and a State/Province on the standard Address field on Leads. But somehow even when I  enter a City and a State and I check the value on the Address field it gives me null. Is there something im doing wrong?

Trigger:

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (before insert, before update) {
    if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert) {
        LeadTriggerHandler.checkAddressCityProvinceInsert(Trigger.new);
    }
    if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate) {
        LeadTriggerHandler.checkAddressCityProvinceUpdate(Trigger.new);        
    }
}
```

Handler:

```
public class LeadTriggerHandler {
    public static void checkAddressCityProvinceInsert(List<Lead> leads) {
        List<Lead> insertLeads = new List<Lead>();
        for (Lead lead : leads) {                
            if (lead.Address.getCity() != null) {
                lead.Address_City_Entered__c = true;
            }
            if (lead.Address.getState() != null) {
                lead.Address_Province_Entered__c = true;
            }
            if (lead.Address_City_Entered__c && lead.Address_Province_Entered__c) {
                insertLeads.add(lead);
            }

        }
    }
    public static void checkAddressCityProvinceUpdate(List<Lead> leads) {
        List<Lead> updateLeads = new List<Lead>();
        for (Lead lead : leads) {
            System.debug(String.valueOf(lead.Address));
            if (lead.Address.getCity() != null) {
                lead.Address_City_Entered__c = true;
            }
            if (lead.Address.getState() != null) {
                lead.Address_Province_Entered__c = true;
            }
            if (lead.Address_City_Entered__c && lead.Address_Province_Entered__c) {
                updateLeads.add(lead);
            }
        }
        update updateLeads;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try `lead.City` then!

Comment: OMG @Ashwani that was it!

Comment: So I should post it as answer! but someone did it :D but had to add expl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger:

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (before insert, before update) {
    if (Trigger.isBefore) {
        LeadTriggerHandler.checkAddressCityProvinceInsert(Trigger.new);
    }    
}
```

Handler:

```
public class LeadTriggerHandler {
    public static void checkAddressCityProvinceInsert(List<Lead> leads) {

        for (Lead lead : leads) {              
            if (lead.city != null) {                                  
                lead.Address_City_Entered__c = true;              
            }                                          
            if (lead.city != null) {             
                lead.Address_Province_Entered__c = true;                
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace all instances of `lead.Address` with `lead.City`, `Lead.State` and `Lead.Country` wherever relevant.

This is a kind of bug that `Address` method don't return value.